# Why does Intellisense suggest this extension method for all types in VS2017?

Tags: c#, generics, intellisense

I have some code

```
public interface ISettable<TValue>
{
}

public class Control<TValue> : ISettable<TValue>
{
}

public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static TControl Set<TControl, T>(this TControl control, T value) where TControl : ISettable<T>
    {
        return control;
    }
}
```

In VS2015, Intellisense does not suggest this extension all types, but in VS2017, this extension is suggested for every type, even `object`.

Why is this method suggested when the type does not implement `ISettable<T>`?

Visual Studio 2017
[image]

Visual Studio 2015
[image]

Comment: What? Can you please expand on your questions as they are not very clear.

Comment: This code is working for me, tried doing  `var x = new Control<int>().Set(1);` with no issues.

Comment: can you please make it very clear what is behaving in an unexpected or confusing way? ideally including any error messages etc that happen?

Comment: 1 working, my bad, I expect Set(int value), actual Set(T value), but Set("string") not working its correct. But I have this extension in IntelliSense list for object type

Comment: This code also works `var x = new Control<string>().Set("string");`  Can you show the code you are using that does not work for you?

Comment: no, it's correct that var x = new Control<int>().Set("string"); not working

Comment: Please add a full example, it's not clear what you expect to work that isn't working.

Comment: Update my question

Comment: This is *still* unclear to me. Are you saying that `new object().Set("x")` compiles but shouldn't? Or is it just Intellisense?

Comment: new object().Set("x") not compiles, it's correct
It's compiles, but Intellisense propose .Set(T value) for all types, but I want that Intellisense propose .Set(string value) for ISettable<string> only

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused about generic types in C#. Your `TValue` type (which doesn't have any constraints) is exactly the same as `T` in your extension method, you're just calling it with a different name (like with formal method parameters).

You method:

```
public static TControl Set<TControl, T>(this TControl control, T value)
    where TControl : ISettable<T>
```

Will actually be available for any `Control<TValue>` instance, and that `T` parameter will be the actual `TValue` type for the instance you're calling the extension method on.

That said, unless you have some other code not shown there, that interface makes little sense on its own: why don't you have a `Set` method in the interface itself rather than in an extension method? You could also make the interface [controvariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) while you're at it. Like this:

```
public interface ISettable<in T>
{
    void Set(T value);
}

public class Control<T> : ISettable<T>
{
    public void Set(T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, you'd already have your `Set` method declared in the interface, which would be cleared for devs using that interface.

**EDIT:** in order to have a fluent interface while supporting multiple interfaces, you could just declare the interface methods explicitly, in order to "hide" them when calling the extension methods (otherwise you wouldn't be able to resolve the overload there), like this:

```
public interface ISettable<in T>
{
    void Set(T value);
}

public interface IClickable
{
    void Click();
}

public class Control<T> : ISettable<T>, IClickable
{
    void ISettable<T>.Set(T value) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    void IClickable.Click() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static class FluentExtensions
{
    public static TControl Set<TControl, T>(this TControl source, T value)
        where TControl : ISettable<T>
    {
        source.Set(value);
        return source;
    }

    public static TControl Click<TControl>(this TControl source)
        where TControl : IClickable
    {
        source.Click();
        return source;
    }
}
```

And then you'd be able to add an arbitrary number of interfaces, and use them like this:

```
new Control<int>().Set(4).Click();
new Control<String>().Click().Set("It works!");
```

Comment: I want fluent interface, C# have 2 ways for fluent interface, extensions and IControl<TControl>. Both ways broken.

Comment: @B.Vandyshev Can't you just make the `Set` method return the same `ISettable<T>` instance, or just declare a standalone method in the `Control<T>` class that returns `this`, in order to have a fluent interface? I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: what about class Control<T> : ISettable<T>, IClickable ?

Comment: @B.Vandyshev I've updated my answer with a solution that works for an arbitrary number of additional interfaces, with the fluent pattern that you're looking for here.

Comment: Set in FluetExtensions Equals my Fluent, and have some troubles with IntelliSence, I update my question

Comment: @B.Vandyshev Ok, now that you've posted those pictures I got what you mean, and I can confirm I'm seeing that behavior on my end as well. It does look like a glitch in IntelliSense to be honest (it suggests `Set` even on a `String`)

Comment: public static TControl Set<TControl>(this TControl control, string value) where TControl : ISettable<string> working fine, but if I use T its not working

Comment: @B.Vandyshev With "`T` is not working" you mean you have that problem with IntelliSense, or some other issue? As far as the wrong suggestion, I don't think there's much we can do about it, other than report the issue.